# Парсер на Python и работа с csv файлом

Tags: python, парсер, csv, requests, beautiful-soup

Небольшая пред история: увидел эту картинку в просторах интернета[image: введите сюда описание изображения]после  этого хотелось сделать что-то подобное и решил спарсить страницу [Supernatural на IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/episodes?season=1). Я спарсил рейтинг вот в таком виде

```
[
   [{1: '8,7'}, {2: '8,0'}, {3: '8,1'}, {4: '8,2'}, {5: '8,5'}, {6: '8,4'}, {7: '8,0'}, {8: '7,0'}, {9: 
   '8,9'}, {10: '8,5'}, {11: '8,7'}, {12: '8,9'}, {13: '7,4'}, {14: '8,3'}, {15: '8,4'}, {16: '8,6'}, 
   {17: 
   '8,4'}, {18: '8,7'}, {19: '8,8'}, {20: '8,5'}, {21: '8,9'}, {22: '9,3'}], # SEASON 1
   [{1: '9,3'}, {2: '8,2'}, {3: '8,3'}, {4: '8,1'}, {5: '8,6'}, {6: '8,4'}, {7: '8,7'}, {8: '8,8'}, {9: 
   '8,8'}, {10: '8,6'}, {11: '8,5'}, {12: '9,0'}, {13: '8,1'}, {14: '8,9'}, {15: '9,2'}, {16: '8,9'}, 
   {17: '8,8'}, {18: '8,6'}, {19: '8,7'}, {20: '9,4'}, {21: '9,2'}, {22: '9,5'}] # SEASON 2
]
```

приступил к записи csv файла, и никак не могу записать данные в колонну

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/episodes'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'}

FILE = 'supernatural.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find('select', id='bySeason').find_all('option')

    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text())
    else:
        return 1


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='list_item')
    episodes = []
    b = 0
    for item in items:
        episodes.append({
            b: item.find(
                'span', class_='ipl-rating-star__rating').get_text().replace('.', ',')
        })
        b += 1

    return episodes

    def save_file(items,path):
        with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow([season for season in range(0, len(items)+1)]) # тут я пытался создать верхние числа (СЕЗОНЫ)
            c = []
            for item in items: # тут выяснял сколько максимум серий в сезоне
                if len(item) > len(c):
                    c = item
            for season in range(1, len(c) + 1): # боковая нумерация серий
                writer.writerow([season])

            for i in range(len(items)): # пытался записать в колонну но получилось все в одну колонну
                for j in range(1, len(items[i])):
                    writer.writerow([items[i][j][j]])

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        sp = []
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        for page in range(1, 4):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {4}...')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'season': page})
            sp.extend([get_content(html.text)])
        # get_content(html.text)
        save_file(sp, FILE)

    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

если знаете как можно это записать правильно поделитесь пожалуйста или дайте направление в какую сторону двигаться(например по другому собрать(спарсить) массив)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно попробовать как-то так

на случай разного кол-ва серий в сезоне, можно воспользоваться zip_longest

```
items = [
   [{1: '8,7'}, {2: '8,0'}, {3: '8,1'}, {4: '8,2'}, {5: '8,5'},], # SEASON 1
   [{1: '9,3'}, {2: '8,2'}, {3: '8,3'}] # SEASON 2
]


class writer :
  def writerow(s) : print(s)

from itertools import zip_longest

writer.writerow(['']+[season for season in range(1, len(items)+1)]) # тут я пытался создать верхние числа (СЕЗОНЫ)
c = []
for item in items: # тут выяснял сколько максимум серий в сезоне
    if len(item) > len(c):
        c = item

for i in zip_longest(range(1, len(c) + 1),*items): 
  writer.writerow([i[0]]+ list(map(lambda x: '' if x is None else list(x.values())[0], i[1:])))
```

вот тка получается

```
['', 1, 2]
[1, '8,7', '9,3']
[2, '8,0', '8,2']
[3, '8,1', '8,3']
[4, '8,2', '']
[5, '8,5', '']
```